# remove add to cart form field

Tags: magento2.3

Hello i have following problems. I have an page_layout and inside of it i have an layout called `dynamic.xml`

I tried to remove the form field where you can click "Add to cart" and the quantity:

First attempt i tried with `product.info.addtocart` and set it to `remov=true` didnt work.

I also tried `product.info.options.bottom` but still there.

Has anybody an idea how to remove the form?

Remove this form here with xml

[image]

Comment: remove add to cart button ? please explain more.

Comment: @Msquare i have added an image what i want to remove. the form input with the button and the qty input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Use this line into your default.xml layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info" remove="true"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i used it in my `dynamic.xml` and it worked